# Retrieve intermediate files generated by preprocessor

Tags: fortran, preprocessor, gnu

How could I retrieve the intermediate files generated by the preprocessor, using GNU compiler?

I typically have Fortran sources that I compile with `-x f95-cpp-input` option for preprocessing, and I would like to retrieve the result. I tested different things, including using the `-save-temps` option (but the output is not really human-readable) and the `-fdump-fortran-original` option (that I found already too strongly modified by the compiler to be useful). I had a look in the GNU documentation, but could not find anything more useful.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `-cpp -E` and you have the result of the preprocessing in the standard output.

> -E  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler
>   proper.  The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which
>   is sent to the standard output.
>
> Input files that don't require preprocessing are ignored.

(from `man gcc`)